# Finding E((X-2)²)

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation

This is a practice quiz as I have a test in a few days. 
I've already completed the first and second questions and my answers are: 
(1) h = 0.4
(2) k = 30

I'm struggling on question 3, I know how to find E(X) using the x•p(x) method but how do I find E((X-2)²). I tried (X-2)²•p(x) but I'm not sure that it's the correct answer. Any help is greatly appreciated![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz3c6.jpg)

Comment: Your method for question 3 looks valid.

Comment: I got 81.8 and the answer says 80.6 so I'm really scratching my head here

Comment: you are indeed right, $E((X-2)^2)=\sum_{i=1}^4 p(X_i)(X_i-2)^2$

Comment: the answer is wrong and you are right

Comment: Please use MathJax to properly type out images and your work. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{align}E[(X-2)^2] &= E[X^2-4X+4]\\
&= E[X^2]-4E[X]+E[4]\\
&= \sum_xx^2p(x)-4\sum_xxp(x)+4\\
&= 93.8 - 4\times4+4\\
&= 81.8 
\end{align}$

On a side note: $E[g(X)]=\displaystyle{\sum_x}g(x)p(x)$.

Answer (score 5):

**(a)**  We require the sum of all probabilities to be $1$, so $h = 0.4$.

**(b)**  We require $$4 = \operatorname{E}[X] = (-1)(0.2) + 0(0.3) + k(0.1) + (3)(0.4) = 1 + k/10,$$ hence $k = 30$.

**(c)** We compute $$\operatorname{E}[(X-2)^2] = (-1-2)^2(0.2) + (0-2)^2(0.3) + (30-2)^2 (0.1) + (3-2)^2 (0.4) = 81.8.$$

It is worth noting that the value of $80.6$ is obtained if you do not include the second term, $(0-2)^2 (0.3)$.  It seems likely that whoever computed the solution failed to realize that even if $X = 0$ contributes nothing to the expectation, once you compute $(X-2)^2 = 4$, this does contribute.  They probably dropped the term because it was dropped when computing $\operatorname{E}[X]$.